# what is the replacement for gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window().get_pointer() which is now deprecated

Tags: python-3.x, replace, gtk3, deprecated

I am using Python 3 and GTK 3, running Debian Buster. I need to find the mouse pointer location on the screen globally, not just within the application's own windows.

I used to use `gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window().get_pointer()` and it works, but this was marked as deprecated in an error message. I searched all over the place and found references in GTK 3 documentation to "devices" but got lost pretty fast. Experimenting, I was not able to find out how to do this. I might have succeeded if I had understood how to get a "device," - not a specific device, but just the "device" representing the mouse pointer as it appears on the screen. I do not care what device is putting the pointer there. For now, I did what I needed to do using XWindows calls, but this seems too specific to the OS and I would like to stick with GTK for this.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely obvious:

```c
GdkDisplay * gdk_display_get_default (void);
// then pass it to
GdkSeat * gdk_display_get_default_seat (GdkDisplay *display);
// then pass it to
GdkDevice * gdk_seat_get_pointer (GdkSeat *seat);
// and finally, pass it to
void gdk_device_get_position (GdkDevice *device, ... );
```

Honestly, IDK what I'm doing and GDK documentation doesn't have a single place to describe all those Screens, Displays, Monitors etc, but try this.

Comment: Someone wants to edit my post. I do not understand the suggested edits. I am using Python. I do not understand the suggested code above because it is not Python. I would appreciate working Python code. Many thanks.

Comment: @TomSullivan oh yes, I wasn't enough attentive. Edited a little. Translating C code to python is quite straightforfard, prefix goes to module name, next is class name and the rest is function name: `gdk_display_get_default -> Gdk.Display.get_default`